# Calling DLL Method - Method Name non correct

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

Dumb problem.
I am developing an easy DLL which expose one method and a Console Application which call the method. Both are targeting .NET 4.5, and each one is on a own solution.

DLL (MyLib.dll):

```
namespace MyLib{
    public static class MyClass{
        public static void MyMethod(){
}}}
```

CONSOLE APP:

```
using MyLib;

....

MyLib.MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Maybe I am missing something easy.. but I would like to call MyMtehod like this:

```
using MyLib;

....

MyMethod();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `using static`:

```cs
using static MyLib.MyClass;

...

MyMethod();
```

> The `using static` directive names a type whose static members and nested types you can access without specifying a type name.

> The `using static` directive applies to any type that has static members (or nested types), even if it also has instance members. However, instance members can only be invoked through the type instance.

[`using static` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/TZO71219)

Comment: Tried that, but it says that the method doesn't exists in current namespace

Comment: Did you reference your DLL in the project?